# Add title to a web server text file using Vb.net

Tags: php, .net, vb.net

I am using the following code to write a text file to a Apache web server using vb.net via a text box.  The code so far works but I want to give the text file a name. I am using the following php file to write

```
<php
$msg = $_GET[‘w’];
$fp = fopen($logfile, “a”);
fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

And using this vb.net code

```
 Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest .Create(“myserver.com/post.php?w=“ & Textbox1.Text)
```

I want to create a text box in the Vb.net application that will change the name of the written text file. I also don’t know a lot with php.

Comment: I suggest that you use a POST request to pass the data to the server - some characters don't work easily in the query string.

Comment: "I want to give the text file a name"...so send a another parameter containing the filename, then...

Comment: ADyson how do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your PHP implementation to expect another query string parameter with the name of the file and include the same parameter in your call to myserver.com/post.php